# How to programmatically enter text in UITextView at the current cursor position

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, uitextinput

I would like to add (some predefined) text at the current cursor position in a UITextView using Swift. So if I have a UITextField named txtField that has some text in it already such as "this is a beautiful valley" and I tap in the area between "a" and "beautiful" so that the cursor is now in the space between "a" and "beautiful" and then click a Button on my user interface a string of text such as "very" will get typed at the cursor position, so that the text in the UITextView will now become "this is a very beautiful valley". At the end of this operation (after button click event) I would the cursor to be just after the word "very". Many thanks for your help. I can see some question on the forum with similar themes, but the answers are in Objective C. I suicidal like help using Swift.

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... Inside your button's `IBAction` use this (please do not use forced optional unwrapping) or else if the textView has no selection or cursor, the app might crash:

```
let txt = "whatever you want"
if let range = handleToYourTextView.selectedTextRange {
   // From your question I assume that you do not want to replace a selection, only insert some text where the cursor is.
   if range.start == range.end {
      handleToYourTextView.replaceRange(range, withText: txt)
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Greatly appreciated. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
textView.replaceRange(textView.selectedTextRange!, withText: "your text")
```

Answer (score 0):

update:

**Swift 5.2**

```
    let txt = "whatever you want"
    if let range = myTextView.selectedTextRange {
       if range.start == range.end {
        myTextView.replace(range, withText: txt)
       }
```